# Highstock: label the y-axis Maximum

Tags: max, highcharts

Im using highstock to show some measurement values. i set minimum/maximum values for the y-values to enclose the bandwith of the data.

My problem at the moment: i need the top label (maximum) of the y-Axis on the background grid. I tried some code with tickinterval etc, but the maximum is never visible.

this is my conde on jsfiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/ehonk/cuk8a36f/

```
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
           yAxis : {
                min: 100,
                max: 700,
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                title : {
                    text : 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
              enabled: false,
              inputEnabled: false
            },
            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Any Help ? Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Simply set `showLastLabel`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/cuk8a36f/1/